# How to serialize DateTimeOffset from JsonNet?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am attempting to serialize a model into Json format. This is my model:

```
    public class UemSiteAvailabilityDetailsRec
    {
        public string UemAlias;
        public string IpAddress;
        public DateTimeOffset Date;
        public string PlannedOutage;
        public string Severity;
        public string SiteName;
        public string SiteNumber;
        public string SourceAgentIp;
        public string Message;
    }
```

This is my code to serialize an instance of the model:

```
var rec = //GETTING REC FROM DATABASE
var val = JsonNet.Serialize(rec);
```

And after that, my `val` looks like this:

```
{
    "UemAlias": "***.***.**.**",
    "IpAddress": "***.***.**.**",
    "Date": {
        "DateTime": "01\/24\/2019 00:00:21",
        "UtcDateTime": "01\/24\/2019 06:00:21",
        "LocalDateTime": "01\/24\/2019 00:00:21",
        "Date": "01\/24\/2019 00:00:00",
        "Day": 24,
        "DayOfWeek": 4,
        "DayOfYear": 24,
        "Hour": 0,
        "Millisecond": 800,
        "Minute": 0,
        "Month": 1,
        "Offset": {
            "Ticks": -216000000000,
            "Days": 0,
            "Hours": -6,
            "Milliseconds": 0,
            "Minutes": 0,
            "Seconds": 0,
            "TotalDays": -0.25,
            "TotalHours": -6,
            "TotalMilliseconds": -21600000,
            "TotalMinutes": -360,
            "TotalSeconds": -21600
        },
        "Second": 21,
        "Ticks": 636838848218000000,
        "UtcTicks": 636839064218000000,
        "TimeOfDay": {
            "Ticks": 218000000,
            "Days": 0,
            "Hours": 0,
            "Milliseconds": 800,
            "Minutes": 0,
            "Seconds": 21,
            "TotalDays": 0.000252314814814815,
            "TotalHours": 0.00605555555555556,
            "TotalMilliseconds": 21800,
            "TotalMinutes": 0.363333333333333,
            "TotalSeconds": 21.8
        },
        "Year": 2019
    },
    "PlannedOutage": "No",
    "Severity": "Critical",
    "SiteName": "BA_ISSI",
    "SiteNumber": null,
    "SourceAgentIp": null,
    "Message": "SITE TRUNKING, DEVICE CRITICAL MALFUNCTION"
}
```

As you can see, my date object looks like it has more stuff in there than I need. And later, when I try to deserialize the string like this:

```
var rec = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UemSiteAvailabilityDetailsModel>(val);
```

I get the error...

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'Date',
>   line 1, position 64. |

How can I make the serialize function make `DateTimeOffset` serialization more concise and not cause errors?

Comment: Did you mean `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`? I'm not aware of a Json.NET class called just `JsonNet`.

Comment: Also, this isn't the behavior I get from calling `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` - I get something like `"Date":"2019-02-01T22:39:12.3072033+00:00"`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: No, it's definitely `JsonNet.Serialize`. I am forced to use the old Json.Net library. I don't have access to Newtonsoft (as far as I can tell) within my .Net Core project.

Comment: I am not using `JsonConvert`. I am using `JsonNet.Serialize`.

Comment: In that case, what is `JsonNet.Serialize`?  According to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsonnet/info, *Jsonnet is a data templating language which compiles to JSON.*  But it looks like, in the context of your question, it's some method you are calling from some c# code.  What is that method?  We can't answer the question without knowing that.  If it's from some old version of Json.NET, then what version is it?

Comment: `Newtonsoft.Json` has supported .NET Core (and .NET Standard) for *ages* - it was one of the first libraries to adopt it.

Comment: Thanks. After some more investigation, I found that, yes, I can use Newtonsoft. I think some of the warning messages were throwing me off. I'm experienced in .NET, but new to .NET core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't have access to Newtonsoft (as far as I can tell) within my .Net Core project.

Not sure if that is a implementation requirement or not, but **there is** a Newtonsoft.Json nuget package available for .Net Core (currently v. 12.0.1). So in case you are able to reimplement your solution to utilize it, you can solve your issue by installing it and then using it so:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class UemSiteAvailabilityDetailsRec
        {
            public string UemAlias;
            public string IpAddress;
            public DateTimeOffset Date = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(1980, 7, 7));
            public string PlannedOutage;
            public string Severity;
            public string SiteName;
            public string SiteNumber;
            public string SourceAgentIp;
            public string Message;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var toSerialize = new UemSiteAvailabilityDetailsRec();
            string val = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toSerialize);
            Console.WriteLine(val);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

This yields the following json:

```
{
    "UemAlias": "",
    "IpAddress": null,
    "Date": "1980-07-07T00:00:00-05:00",
    "PlannedOutage": null,
    "Severity": null,
    "SiteName": null,
    "SiteNumber": null,
    "SourceAgentIp": null,
    "Message": null
}
```

Comment: Thanks. After some more investigation, I found that, yes, I can use Newtonsoft. I think some of the warning messages were throwing me off. I'm experienced in .NET, but new to .NET core.